# How To Convert Dropdown to checkbox in View page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I'm working with **Dynamic Checkbox**, I trying to get `CheckBox` Value from another already Created table. But When I Do Code For `DropDownList` it can Be Working but same as it is not working for `CheckBox`

1. following is My Method

   ```
   public IEnumerable<clsHobbyList> GetHobby()
           {
               List<clsHobbyList> lstHobby = new List <clsHobbyList>();

               using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddHoby", con);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                   con.Open();
                   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                   while (rdr.Read())
                   {
                       clsHobbyList hby = new clsHobbyList();
                       hby.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                       hby.HobbyName = rdr["HobbyName"].ToString();


                       lstHobby.Add(hby);
                   }
                   con.Close();
               }
               return lstHobby;
           }
   ```
2. Following Is My Controller

   ```
    public ActionResult Create()
           {
               EmployeeDataAccessLayer objemployee = new EmployeeDataAccessLayer();
               clsHobbyList hby = new clsHobbyList();
               ViewBag.Hobby = new SelectList(objemployee.GetHobby(), "Id", "HobbyName");

               return View();
           }
   ```
3. **and this is my View Page, hear How Can I Get CheckBox** ?? please suggest me some solution

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hobby, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
               <div class="col-md-10">

                   @Html.DropDownList("Hobby", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

               </div>
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hobby, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
   ```

   -----------Hear How Can I Get Checkbox--------------------------------------------

Comment: Checkbox for what?

Comment: CheckBox For Hobby Field

Comment: https://exceptionnotfound.net/simple-checkboxlist-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

use Foreach loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model.clsHobbyList)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Id" value="@item.HobbyName" text="@item.HobbyName" name="@item.HobbyName" />
                @item.HobbyName
            }
```